# Javascript: Looping through an object within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have a JSON feed from which I need to extract some information to plot some markers onto a map. In order to do so I need to loop through the JSON feed, then loop through a particular object within the array.

I can get it to loop through the top level (category), but attempting to loop through each category is working as expected - I get the same cateogry repeated equal to the number categories.

The structure of the array/object is as so:

```
- activities
    |_ category
    |_ acf
        |_ activity_listing
            |_ name
            |_ latitude
            |_ longitude
            |_ name
            |_ latitude
            |_ longitude
    |_ category
    |_ acf
        |_ activity_listing
            |_ name
            |_ latitude
            |_ longitude
            |_ name
            |_ latitude
            |_ longitude
```

Each category has an activity listing with multiple items (name, lat, lng).

My code is setup as below:

```
var activitiesLocationList = this.activitiesLocations;

for (var i = 0; i < activitiesLocationList.length; i++) {

    activitiesLocationList[0]['acf']['activity_listing'].forEach(function(item) {

        var placeName = item['activity_listing-name'];
        var placeLatitude = parseFloat(item['activity-listing_latitude']);
        var placeLongitude = parseFloat(item['activity-listing_longitude']);

        console.log('Place Name: ' + placeName);

    })
}
```

The output is:

```
'Place Name: Karijini National Park'
'Place Name: Staircase to the Moon'
'Place Name: Millstream Chichester National Park'
'Place Name: Dampier Archipelago'
'Place Name: Murujuga National Park'
'Place Name: Montebello Islands'
'Place Name: Karijini National Park'
'Place Name: Staircase to the Moon'
'Place Name: Millstream Chichester National Park'
'Place Name: Dampier Archipelago'
'Place Name: Murujuga National Park'
'Place Name: Montebello Islands'
```

So it's almost doing what I want, but is only entering the first category. What am I doing wrong?

How do I get it to step through each category, looping the contents as it goes?

Comment: Can you post the input object as *code*, not psuedocode, so we have a [MCVE] to run and debug?

Comment: I will remember for next time, seems the solution has been found already this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually accessing 0th index only when you loop through object. replace `activitiesLocationList[0]['acf']['activity_listing']` with `activitiesLocationList[i]['acf']['activity_listing']`. So your complete code will look like below

```
var activitiesLocationList = this.activitiesLocations;

for (var i = 0; i < activitiesLocationList.length; i++) {

    activitiesLocationList[i]['acf']['activity_listing'].forEach(function(item) {

        var placeName = item['activity_listing-name'];
        var placeLatitude = parseFloat(item['activity-listing_latitude']);
        var placeLongitude = parseFloat(item['activity-listing_longitude']);

        console.log('Place Name: ' + placeName);

    })
}
```

Comment: Of course! This is what happens after 2 weeks of coding for 14+ hours a day! Such a rookie mistake, thank you!   Accepting this answer as it explains the issue, rather than just stating a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass index `i` instead of `0` while you are looping in this line `activitiesLocationList[i]['acf']['activity_listing']....`

Answer (score 1):

I think due to this part of code `activitiesLocationList[0]`, you would always get the first object. 
can change it into `activitiesLocationList[i]` to get each of object data then should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use activitiesLocationList[i] instead of , activitiesLocationList[0] :

```
for (var i = 0; i < activitiesLocationList.length; i++) {

    activitiesLocationList[0]['acf']['activity_listing'].forEach(function(item) {

        var placeName = item['activity_listing-name'];
        var placeLatitude = parseFloat(item['activity-listing_latitude']);
        var placeLongitude = parseFloat(item['activity-listing_longitude']);

        console.log('Place Name: ' + placeName);

    })
}
```